# Web.py | yield data via POST and AJAX (generator function)

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, post, web.py

I am using the **web.py** framework to set up my website. When I click a button, I want to POST data to the server and then send back data via a **generator function / yield**. Basically yield data as it's ready, not wait for my data function to fully finish.

I get [yield to work via GET](http://webpy.org/cookbook/streaming_large_files), but my POST implementations via AJAX is the problem.

```
def POST(self):
    web.header('Content-type','text/html')
    web.header('Transfer-Encoding','chunked')
    yield "hello"
    sleep(10)
    yield "hello"
```

**And my javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#button").click(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "text",
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(data){
                    jQuery("#container").html(data)
                  }
                }); }); });
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
HelloHello (after 10 seconds) 
rather than..
Hello (10 second delay) Hello
```

**Note**: I am using web.py's built in server on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foolish me - AJAX doesn't support streaming. So this is a case when Comet or HTML5 WebSockets will come in handy.